# Remmina Desktop - cannot connect to RDP server

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop, rdp, remmina

Good evening,

I am a new user of Ubuntu, so please be kind to me if I don't fully understand what I am doing or what you'll tell me.

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 a few days ago and everything is fine.

I'm using my laptop to connect through a VPN connection to my computer at my office, which is running Windows 7.

In order to do this, I use the default program which is Remmina (version 1.1.2). I added my server name, user name, password, the protocol security (RDP).

The first time I did it, I had no issue. Then I put my laptop on sleep mode and come back to work and it could not connect anymore to the RDP server...

I tried to change the resolution, the security parameters, etc. and nothing works. I looked on the web and saw that removing the file located at *~/.config/freerdp/known_hosts* should solve my issue but NO. It doesn't.

Eventually it worked again, but when I woke up or powered on my computer it didn't work anymore...

I really tried to look on forums but the solution was always to remove the known_hosts file, which doesn't work.

I decided to reinstall Ubuntu 16.04 to see if it would work better, but it's not the case.

Now in the *~/.config* file, the file *~/freerdp* doesn't even exist, so the *known_hosts* either !!!

I really don't know what to do...

If you could indicate a solution or tell me if you need additional informations to understand where does the problem com, it would be great!

I also tried to launch Remmina from terminal, but it doesn't change. Before I reinstall Ubuntu, I also updated to a newer version, but it was still the same...

I think you've understood : I'm a bit lost.

Thank you to all of you in advance and have a good evening.

PS : I always have this message in terminal when I launch a session :

```
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
loading channel cliprdr
```

*2017-12-08 21:34* : I started Remmina and it's working. It didn't from the application but it worked from the terminal. I'll disconnect the VPN and restart it to check if it still works.

*2017-12-08 21:36* : I disconnected the VPN and restarted the session and "et voilà", it doesn't work anymore.

I have this message in terminal :

```
loading channel cliprdr
tcp_connect: getaddrinfo (Nom ou service inconnu)
Error: protocol security negotiation or connection failure
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
```

*2017-12-08 21:39* : I killed Remmina, restarted it from terminal and got this error but it's working now... :

```
Remmina plugin VNC (type=Protocole) registered.
Remmina plugin VNCI (type=Protocole) registered.
Remmina plugin RDP (type=Protocole) registered.
Remmina plugin RDPF (type=Fichier) registered.
Remmina plugin RDPS (type=Préférence) registered.
Remmina plugin SFTP (type=Protocole) registered.
Remmina plugin SSH (type=Protocole) registered.
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
loading channel cliprdr
tcp_connect: getaddrinfo (Nom ou service inconnu)
Error: protocol security negotiation or connection failure
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
loading channel cliprdr
connected to mypc:3389
svc_plugin_send: VirtualChannelWrite failed 7
svc_plugin_send: VirtualChannelWrite failed 7
svc_plugin_send_event: VirtualChannelEventPush failed 7
svc_plugin_send: VirtualChannelWrite failed 7
```

Comment: Are you sure that your RDP-server works normally? Can you check it from for example Windows?

Comment: Yes. And it worked for 2 times tonight... I disconnected my VPN, restarted Remmina from terminal and it worked, now I again get this message : 

tcp_connect: getaddrinfo (Nom ou service inconnu)
Error: protocol security negotiation or connection failure
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.

Comment: Can you check availability of resources in the VPN-network (with `ping` or with web-browser)? Are you sure that RDP server stays alive after connecting/disconnecting?

Comment: I ping checked my VPN, it's OK.

What do you mean by stays alive after connecting/disconnecting ? Do you mean the parameters remain in Remmina ?

Comment: I mean that RDP server continue to work after disconnecting. In some cases RDP session hangs and user can't connect to the server again. Some versions of Windows supports only two simultaneous RDP-users.

Comment: The remote computer continues to work, yes. I don't unlog the computer, I guess it just locks and then when I come back it unlocks. But when I connected from Windows to Windows I had no issue.

Comment: You may try other RDP client such as [`rdesktop`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/rdesktop). You can install it with `sudo apt-get install rdesktop`.

Comment: I installed rdesktop and started my session, but I still have an error...

So I searched this error specifically and found out that some people had the same issue when they were using the server NAME and not when they were using the IP adress. 

I checked the IP adress of my remote computer from another computer (which is running Windows) and wrote it in Remmina and it seems to be working ... even after several connection/disconnection of my VPN and even after restarting my computer... !

I guess the problem is solved.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Great! I forgot to mention I use connection via IP always. You can answer your question by writing last comment as answer I think.

Answer (score 1):

I installed rdesktop and started my session, but I still have an error... So I searched this error specifically and found out that some people had the same issue when they were using the server NAME and not when they were using the IP adress. I checked the IP adress of my remote computer from another computer (which is running Windows) and wrote it in Remmina and it seems to be working ... even after several connection/disconnection of my VPN and even after restarting my computer... ! I guess the problem is solved. Thank you for your help!